# angularjs ng-repeat with two radio buttons not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi i tried to create a dynamic form with radio button, after in my result i cannot able to form correctly

My code is

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3] track by $index">
  <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
  <td>
    <label>
        <input ng-model="$parent.reservation.gender" type="radio"
               name="gender.$index"
               value="male" checked>
        Male
    </label>

    <label>
        <input ng-model="$parent.reservation.gender" type="radio"
               name="gender.$index"
               value="female" checked>
        Female
    </label>
  </td>
  <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
</tr>
```

I my scenario i have to select  each row's gender but i cannot able to set parameters  to run correctly

[screenshot of my work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIftn.png)

[Plunkr link](http://plnkr.co/hVhaPLz7i1mzEEpNEN92)

Comment: we don't know what `$parent` is from brief layout shown. Create a demo in **[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue)** that replicates problem

Comment: http://plnkr.co/hVhaPLz7i1mzEEpNEN92

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not fully clear from you description what "run correctly" means, so I'm going to guess a bit.

You want to have a `reservation` object (that lives in the parent scope of the `ng-repeat`) hold the properties of N people. In other words, if you had a `ReservationCtrl`, you want it to have an object of the following form:

```
$scope.reservation = 
  [
    {name: "Foo", gender: "male", age: 23},
    {name: "Bar", gender: "female", age: 18},
    // and so on...
  ];
```

So, define a controller:

```
app.controller("ReservationCtrl", function($scope){
  $scope.reservation = [{}]; // array with the an uninitialized person
  $scope.addPerson = function(){ $scope.reservation.push({}); }
});
```

Then in the View:

```
<div ng-repeat="person in reservation">
  <input ng-model="person.name" type="text">
  <label>Male:   
     <input ng-model="person.gender" name="gender{{$index}}" type="radio" value="male">
  </label>
  <label>Female: 
     <input ng-model="person.gender" name="gender{{$index}}" type="radio" value="female">
  </label>
  <input ng-model="person.age" type="number">
</div>
<button ng-click="addPerson()">Add another person</button>
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vns9Ee35kSpFb7T4Dp25?p=preview)

Comment: sorry for not gave brief explanation . but u understand much , thank you. Actually in your plnkr u can see , when i click male everything is selected as male but it need be in that row only

Comment: That's not what I'm seeing - did you click on the [right link](http://plnkr.co/edit/vns9Ee35kSpFb7T4Dp25?p=preview)? Each entry is independent - check again.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/X8YXa5n5gLkjXOTTB7RL?p=preview - i accesses this link when i click the male all males are selected please check your side

Comment: This is your link. My link is in my answer, my comment above, but here it is again: http://plnkr.co/edit/vns9Ee35kSpFb7T4Dp25?p=preview

Comment: Thank you as per your advice its works fine .. updated http://plnkr.co/edit/hVhaPLz7i1mzEEpNEN92?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `checked`. You should initialize you model with value then it will be checked:

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3] track by $index" ng-init="$parent.reservation.gender='female'">
```

Also I bet you mean `name="gender.{{$index}}"` instead of `name="gender.$index"`

http://plnkr.co/edit/X8YXa5n5gLkjXOTTB7RL?p=preview

Comment: he has a few other issues there